# How can I configure Local Search Phase in kie-workbench 7.0.0.beta8

Tags: optaplanner, kie-workbench

Hellow.

I try to use optaplanner and kie-workbench.

My enviroment is JDK 1.8.0 / WildFly 10.1.0 / kie-workbench 7.0.0.beta8.

Like below figure, they only show construction heuristic phase, so I can't define local search phase in score configuration.

Does there need an addition setting for showing local search button?

Or, I skip something to do?

[Score Phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLUlu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is fixed](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-367) in 7.0.0.CR1 which is out now.